# What are the names of Lakshmi Devi as consort of Vishnu in His form as Kurma and Matsya?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, lakshmi

Lakshmi Devi always accompanies Vishnu in each of His incarnations.

What are Her specific forms and names as Shakti of Kurma-Avatara and Matsya-Avatara?

Comment: "Lakshmi Devi always accompanies Vishnu in every of His incarnations."-- how can it be true? let's say Vishnu took avtar as female like Mohini or brahmchari like Parashurama..

Comment: She is always there at His vakshasthalam.

Comment: YDS read https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115945.html for your first point.